# PDF could not be generated!” with wkhtmltopdf in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, wkhtmltopdf, wicked-pdf

I am using wkhtmltopdf(0.10.0 rc2) AND Wicked_pdf(0.9.4) for generating pdf report.

I am getting below error

```
Failed to execute:
"/usr/bin/wkhtmltopdf" -q  --footer-left "[page]" --footer-right "Powered by AMP" --footer-font-size 7    --margin-top 5 --margin-bottom 10 --margin-left 10 --margin-right 10  --page-size "A4"   "file:////tmp/["wicked_pdf", ".html"]29083-0" "/tmp/["wicked_pdf_generated_file", ".pdf"]29083-0" 
Error: PDF could not be generated!
```

my controller:

```
render :pdf => "#{@note_name}",:layout => '/layouts/pdf_template.html.erb', :template=>'/leasing_activity/lease_act_pdf.html.erb'
```

gemfile:

```
gem "wicked_pdf","0.9.4"
gem "wkhtmltopdf-binary"
```

initializers/wicked_pdf.rb:

```
WickedPdf.config = {
  :exe_path => '/usr/bin/wkhtmltopdf'

}
```

Comment: That tempfile path is messed up. Not 100% sure why, but wicked_pdf version 0.9.4 is for wkhtmltopdf versions less than 10. Try either downgrading wkhtmltopdf or using wicked_pdf master in your Gemfile: `gem 'wicked_pdf', github: 'mileszs/wicked_pdf'`

Comment: Yeah that path is really not right. Try running said command in the console and see what happens. Also the command line arguments have double spaces, but I don't think it's that serious - but annoying anyway. I use wkhtmltopdf with c# and calling it directly instead of using a wrapper is very easy, I'm guessing ruby can do that just as well, so I suggest you try that too!